# PHP get multiple data from one row in Database

Tags: php, row

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVy5T.png) I have one row with images names  like this , row_multiple_imgs['path_one,path_two,path_tree'];
all are separate with comma how can I get this paths ? What i want to get is return 3 different paths
I'm not sure that foreach loop can help; any solution to this ?

what I what get is thee different names from one row Independent from each other.

for example

```
foreach($row['multi_imag'] as img){
return $img;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you show the table schema (the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`), some sample data, and the result you want?

Comment: In general, `SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM table_name WHERE ...`

Comment: It's also generally poor DB design to put comma-separated values in a table column. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: Okay i have one row with name : multi_images['imaga_name_one, image_name_two,image_name_three']; and inside this row i have three different paths . So i want return em as an individual part, as in associative array with different values

Comment: That's what you wrote in the question. Saying it again doesn't clarify. Please click [Edit] and add more details to the question.

Comment: now is better ?

Comment: No. Can you show the table schema (the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`), some sample data, and the result you want?

Comment: as you can see in img i have row with 3 different paths

Comment: `foreach (explode(',', $row['multi_imag']) as $img)`?

Comment: Please post plain text, not images. And that image is so tiny it's unreadable.

Comment: Yes this i want

Comment: So what's the problem? If you have a comma-separated list, explode() should be the obvious solution.